# Cannot get else condition to display

Tags: ruby

I am working through a codeacademy project and I cannot get a certain condition to display. Here is my code.

When I select `add` and choose a movie to add, I want it to let me know if the movie I input already exists in the hash. When I type in a movie that already exists in the hash, it asks me for the rating anyway. I believe I have the `else` statement in the right place, but it does not seem to be working.

Update: I changed these two lines of code (removing the .to_sym)

```
title = title
if movies[title].nil?
```

It does not allow me to enter duplicates.

Now when I choose "add" then try to add "Memento" I get the error message 
"#{title} already exists. Its rating is #{rating}!" #{rating} produces an integer of 1 (which makes no sense since the integer value is 4).

```
movies = {
"Memento" => 4,
"Inception" => 3,
"The Prestige" => 2,
"Interstellar" => 1
}

puts "What would you like to do?"
choice = gets.chomp.downcase

case choice

# ADD
when "add" 
puts "What would you like to add?"
title = gets.chomp
title = title
if movies[title].nil?
puts "What its rating? (enter 1-4)"
rating = gets.chomp
movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}"
else puts "#{title} already exists. Its rating is #{rating}!"
end

# UPDATE
when "update" 
puts "Updated!"

# DISPLAY
when "display" 
puts "Movies!"

# DELETE
when "delete" 
puts "Deleted!"

# ERROR
else 
puts "Error!"
```

end

Comment: What is your question? What problem do you have?

Comment: Does it let you add the same movie twice, or just let you add one of your predefined movies?  If it is just your predefined movies then you need to read up on the difference between symbols and strings in Ruby.

Comment: Your `if movies[title.to_sym].nil?` will always be satisfied unless you add a symbol key to `movies`.

Comment: Let me update the question since the situation has changed.

Comment: So you want movies to rate and add if does not already exists. Right?

Comment: When I enter a movie title that is already in the hash (as a key), I want a message to tell me that the movie already exists in the hash. In order words, I want the message ""#{title} already exists. Its rating is #{rating}!" to display when I enter a key that already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you removed the to_sym calls you didn't remove all of them:

```
movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
```

and

```
Its rating is #{rating}!"
```

doesn't reference the movie rating it references the variable rating.  Which hasn't been set yet.

the else block should be

```
rating = movies[title]
puts "#{title} already exists. Its rating is #{rating}!"
```

Comment: Thank you that was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Since `title` is a string, you don't need to convert it to a symbol.  And then you can use `Hash::include?` to see if the key exists.

```
# ADD
when "add" 
  puts "What would you like to add?"
  title = gets.chomp
  # title = title.to_sym                # delete this line since the hash keys are strings
  if !movies.include? title             # use Hash::include? to see if key exists
    puts "What its rating? (enter 1-4)"
    rating = gets.chomp
    ...
  else
    puts "Movie already exists. Its rating is #{movies[title]}!"   # remove .to_sym
end
```